# automatic VMware snaphots creation

Tags: java, python, bash, networking, vmware

I need to run different Malware samples on Vmware and record the network traffic for each sample.

For each run I need to ensure that the image is clean,so I will use snapshot for the original image, execute the sample, record the network traffic and finally restore to the clean snapshot.

The thing is I have large number of samples (more than a thousand). So is there any way to automate the process? It would be great if you help me in where to start scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any scripting API: [vSphere SDK for Python](https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/), [vSphere SDK for Perl](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/index.html), [PowerShell interface for managing vSphere](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/automationtools/powercli), [vmrun](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_vmrun_command.pdf) command-line utility. Or [VMware vSphere Web Services SDK](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/) using SOAP. All of them support operations with snapshots. For example, the following script uses the vmrun utility to create a snapshot and rollback to it:

```
vmrun -T vc -h 10.1.1.44 -u root -p vmware snapshot "[datacenter-2/datastore1] CENTER/CENTER.vmx" CleanSnapshot
vmrun -T vc -h 10.1.1.44 -u root -p vmware -gu Administrator -gp P@ssword runScriptInGuest "[datacenter-2/datastore1] CENTER/CENTER.vmx" "" "echo Test > c:\test.txt"
vmrun -T vc -h 10.1.1.44 -u root -p vmware revertToSnapshot "[datacenter-2/datastore1] CENTER/CENTER.vmx" CleanSnapshot
```